# Recursive function to browse a tree with controlled depth in Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a data structure that is composed of tree. each parent holds 3 children. I want to create a recursive function in javascript (specially for node.js) that will browse that tree completely until it reaches a depth defined (let's assume the depth is 3 here).
So I've written this function :

```
 var i=0;
function recursive (depth) {
    console.log("total = "+ i++);
    console.log("the depth is "+ depth)
    if (depth>3){return} else
        {depth++;
            for (j = 1; j <= 3; j++){
                recursive(depth);
            };
        }
    }

    recursive(0);
```

Now form the output of this program, I guess my function browses the first branch and when it reaches the depth, scans the 3 children and returns. But I want it to scan the other children so the total of nodes reached should be 1 + 3 + 9 = 13 and not 6 that is shown in my total.

Can you help me with this please?

Comment: Could you provide your input and expected output?

Comment: var i = 1;
    function recursive (depth) {
        if (depth>=3) return;
        console.log("total = "+ i++);
        console.log("the depth is "+ depth)
        for (var j = 1; j <= 3; j++){
            recursive(depth + 1);
        }
    }
    
    recursive(0);

Comment: There should have a starting node, thats why I set "I" to be one.

Comment: Yeah it's hard to tell what result you want given the code you've shown. What is the function supposed to return?

Comment: There is not input here, but i've set the depth to 3 and I can change it whenever I want. The output is "total = 0
the depth is 1
total = 1
the depth is 2
total = 2
the depth is 3
total = 3
the depth is 4
total = 4
the depth is 4
total = 5
the depth is 4 "  but I want it to go all the way to total = 12

Comment: please add the tree/data structure/data as well.